# Is there a proper way to include images in the margins a an R Bookdown project?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, tufte

I am working towards writing a textbook using R Bookdown, and I want to include pictures in the margins of the text. However, after trying multiple methods none of them seem to actually populate the image in the correct place. I have tried all the options in r bookdown manual and the instructions for using tufte style https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/tufte-figures.html.

To make sure I am not having problems with conflicting packages I have been creating a fresh project then pasting the following code into the end of the index.Rmd file.

```
{r fig-margin, fig.margin=TRUE}
knitr::include_graphics('apple.png')

^![](C:\Users\n298l621\Documents\TESTING\apple.png)

{marginfigure, echo = TRUE}
knitr::include_graphics('apple.png')
```

The following image is the result of me either knitting the index.Rmd document or building the whole book using the build menu:

[image: results]

As you can see, the images are populating but certainly not in the margin. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to use r chunk inserting picture in the margin. Here is my document using latex in Rmarkdown insert the compamy logo in left-top margin.

````
---
documentclass: ctexart
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm
pagesize: a4paper
output:
  rticles::ctex:
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: no
mainfont: 更纱黑体 UI SC #LiberationSerif
sansfont: 更纱黑体 UI SC Xlight #LiberationSans
monofont: 等距更纱黑体 SC Light #LiberationMono
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{fancyhdr}    #load fancyhdr for page header or foot
    - \usepackage{booktabs}
    # - \usepackage{longtable}
    - \usepackage{array}
    - \usepackage{multirow}
    - \usepackage{wrapfig}
    - \usepackage{float}
    - \usepackage{colortbl}
    - \usepackage{pdflscape}
    - \usepackage{tabu}
    - \usepackage{threeparttable}
    - \usepackage{threeparttablex}
    - \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
    - \usepackage{makecell}
    - \usepackage{xeCJK}
---
\addtolength{\headheight}{1.5cm}
\pagestyle{fancyplain} 
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{cdmlogo.png}} # put the logo at top-left 
\fancyhead[C]{打印日期\today}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r include=FALSE, label='oracle.connection'}
library(tidyverse)
library(ROracle)
library(kableExtra)
````

Comment: thank you for the quick response @drunkfish69. I had not thought to use latex by itself yet.

Answer (score 0):

Could you include an example of the yaml front matter which you are using in your `.Rmd`?

A document produced with the following code:

````
---
title: "An MWE of tufte"
author: "chefnate119"
output:
  tufte::tufte_html: default
---

```{r fig-margin, fig.margin=TRUE}
plot(cars)
```
````

Produces the following document

[image]

and to a pdf

````
---
title: "An MWE of tufte"
author: "chefnate119"
output:
  tufte::tufte_handout: default
---

```{r fig-margin, fig.margin=TRUE}
plot(cars)
```
````

[image]

Comment: I will try your header now. The YAML I was using looked like

Comment: --- 
        title: "A Minimal Book Example"
        author: "Yihui Xie"
        date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
        site: bookdown::bookdown_site
        documentclass: book
        bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
        biblio-style: apalike
        link-citations: yes
        description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a 
        book. The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook."
        ---

Comment: I tried copying your YAML into my document and got this error "
processing file: index.Rmd
Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1], params.src, markdown_mode) : 
  Duplicate chunk label 'fig-margin', which has been used for the chunk:
plot(cars)
Calls: <Anonymous> ... process_file -> split_file -> lapply -> FUN -> parse_block
Execution halted

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was able to get that to work with the image in the margin. I do have to say I'm not a huge fan of the tufte style. I saw that I can edit the appearence using the .css file created by R but I was wondering if you know of a way to achieve the same goal in regular markdown without having to make those edits. Do you know of a method for this?

Comment: I don't know how to do this, apologies. i think the best approach for here would be to stick with the tufte output format and tweak the css to get a style you like more.